# a problem which readings from lidar data through node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

On my Raspberry Pi 2B Ubuntu Mate 1604 running ROS kinetic and is connected Lidar Hokuyo URG-04LX. Data from lidar I needed to get into Matlab 16b running on a laptop.

In Matlab see a list of nodes from ROS, urg_out can even ping from lidar data but I read wrong.

Raspberry Pi is a laptop connected via an Ethernet cable, IP adress settings is OK.

```
rpi orders:
settings Lidar:
cd ..
cd ..
cd ..
sudu chmod 777 dev/ttyACM0

run roscore:
cd /opt/ros/kinetic/bin
roscore

another console:
cd
cd catkin_ws/devel
./setup.bash
rosrun urg_node urg_node

RPI will establish a master ros to the desired address.
rpi write - streaming data

Matlab code:

clc;
close all;
clear all;

rosshutdown
rosinit ('192.168.1.10')

rostopic list
rostopic info /scan
rs=rossubscriber('scan')
receive(rs, 100)

Matlab write:
Operation terminated by user during robotics.ros.internal.Util/waitUntilTrue (line
67)


In robotics.ros.Subscriber/receive (line 322)
                util.waitUntilTrue( @() obj.MessageListener.isNewMessage, timeout );

In Matlab_lidar (line 11)
receive(rs, 100)
```

The problem is that matlab does not list data from lidar.
Please do not know what could be wrong?

Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256811/a-problem-which-readings-from-lidar-data-through-node/) by [Petr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29665/petr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-12**:
"But I read data wrong" sounds like the problem here, but there's nothing in that description that might help debug the issue. You'll get better answers if you post your matlab code and post or describe the output, what you think it should be doing, and what it is actually doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This looks vaguely like a network issue; I advise that you read the [ROS Network Setup](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) and [ROS Multiple Machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) tutorials and make sure that the ROS_MASTER_URI and hostnames are configured correctly on your machines, and that you can do a `rosnode ping` from the computer running matlab to the urg_node on your Raspberry Pi. I don't know much about the ROS bindings for Matlab, so the commands in matlab may be a little different from the tutorials.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Petr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29665/petr/) on 2017-03-19**:
Thank you very much for the comment and interest. Raspberry and computer goes to ping each other.

**Comment by [Petr](https://answers.ros.org/users/29665/petr/) on 2017-03-26**:
I tried it yet again. Ping rosout passes, ping urg_node fails. Please do not know what could be wrong? Thank you.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-26**:
It sounds like something is missing from your network setup, but it's difficult to debug this without seeing the complete configuration of the routes, IP address assignments, ROS_IP, ROS_HOSTNAME, ROS_MASTER_URI, which nodes are running, which machine they're on, and `rosnode info` for every node.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-26**:
If the wiki doesn't help, I suggest you [watch my talk about networking](https://vimeo.com/67806888) and [read the slides](http://roscon.ros.org/2013/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Networking-for-ROS-Users.pdf) from ROSCon 2013.